# How can I overcome race conditions within directives without a timeout function?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying my hand at creating a directive. Things simply weren't working so I simplified things until I found this basic race condition issue causing problems for me. In my directive's controller I need to do some checks like...

```
if ($scope.test.someValue === true) { $scope.test.anotherValue += 1; }
```

Here's my basic directive with some logs to illustrate how this issue manifests.

```
app.directive('myDirective', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            test: '='
        },
        template: '<div><pre>{{ test | json }}</pre></div>',
        controller: function ($scope, $timeout) {

        // this logs undefined
        console.log($scope.test);

        // this logs the scope bound 'test' object
        $timeout(function() {
            console.log($scope.test);
        }, 300);

        }
    };
});
```

What is the correct way to work with this race condition? I'm worried that in the real world this timeout function is going to work or fail based on how long an api call takes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember that at the "link" phase (when you assign your controller), the `$scope.test` variable has not been assigned yet - hence the `undefined`

The `$timeout(fn, timeout)` is a way to execute something which will affect something in the $scope. You can set your $timeout() value to 0 and it will still work. The reason for this is because the $timeout(...) function will be deferred till after the current `$digest()` cycle.

**References:**
[$timeout()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24timeout)
[$digest()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope#%24digest)

Additionally, if you want to watch for changes in a particular value you can do:

```
$scope.$watch("test.somevalue", function(new_val, old_val) {
    console.log("somevalue changed!! - increment othervalue");
    $scope.othervalue += 1;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The controller is instantiated during the pre-linking phase (when the scope of the directive is not bound to any parent scope yet).

The controller is where you put the business logic of the directive.

Any initialization code (especially code that depends on the bindings to the parent scope), should be run at the linking phase (i.e. using the `link` property of the Directive Definition Object).

```
app.directive('myDirective', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            test: '='
        },
        template: '<div><pre ng-click="someFunc()">{{ test | json }}</pre></div>',
        controller: function ($scope) {
            /* No two-way bindings yet: test -> undefined */

            /* Business logic can go here */
            $scope.someFunc = function () {
                alert('I implement the business logic !');
            };
        },
        link: function postLink(scope, elem, attrs) {
            /* Bindings are in place. Safe to check up on test. */
            console.log($scope.test);
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: That makes sense. Is it simple to set controller values from the link function? For example based on your example above. If the controller contained $scope.someConstant = null; Could I then just update that value when the link function initializes by having this in the link function $scope.someConstant = $scope.test.someProperty; ? Or how does communication work between the two functions?

Comment: Yeah, the `$scope` injected into the controller and the `scope` argument passed to the link function are the same. Updating tha value in one place updates it the other as well (since it's the same object).

Comment: @Constellates: I don't mean to be !@#$%, but the accepted answer is **not** _"the correct way to work with this race condition"_. (Not that I care much - just saying...)

Comment: No worries, I'm still new to custom directives so I can't always decipher what is best practice. Though I am still having the same race issue with your solution. The console.log in the link function is logging undefined. If I put it in a $scope.$watch within the link function it works again.

Comment: @Constellates: Maybe I got something wrong, because it seems to **[work for me](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/6Dv2s/)**. You probably meant something different though.

Comment: I made a plunker with most of my actual directive minus the template. I'm only really using $scope.total to illustrate the problem but wanted to give a better idea of the context. It's for an image and video gallery and it's important for the ui that the controller knows how many images have been initialized and whether a video is present. I added a timeout function to simulate a potentially slow api call. http://jsfiddle.net/constellates/F78kv/1/

Comment: @Constellates: Sorry, I didn't realize data was coming from the backend. In that case neither the `link` function nor a `$timeout` are reliable solution. You need to either use a `$watch` or (the best and more "Angularish" is to) have a service that fetches the data and returns a promise. Take a look at promices and specifically Angular's **[`$q` service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)**.

Answer (score 0):

One way of working with Race conditions is to [$watch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope#%24watch) the variable you want to use, and when its value changes to the value you desire (`!= undefined` in your case) you can work with that variable. The expression that needs to be watched gets evaluated every `$digest` cycle. Here's an example for your case:

```
$scope.$watch('test', function(val){
    if(val != undefined) {
        if ($scope.test.someValue === true) { $scope.test.anotherValue += 1; }
    }
})
```